# What is the divergence of a distribution?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open
- $\mathcal D(\Omega):=C_c^\infty(\Omega)$

If $p\in \mathcal D'(\Omega)$, then $$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i}(\phi):=-p\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_i}\right)\;\;\;\text{for }i\in\left\{1,\ldots,d\right\}\text{ and }\phi\in\mathcal D(\Omega)$$ and $$\nabla p(\phi):=\sum_{i=1}^d\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i}(\phi_i)\;\;\;\text{for }\phi\in\mathcal D(\Omega)^d\;.$$

> Is there some notion of the *divergence* of a distribution too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In distribution theory, many notions are generalizations of what happens in space $L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$. The distributional derivative is an operator of type $D^\alpha : \mathcal{D}'(\Omega) \longrightarrow \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$, its restriction on $L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ is what many authors call weak derivative, in this sense, weak and distributional derivative are the same thing. That said, you just know what is weak gradient to know what is the distributional gradient. The divergence follows then by an appropriate scalar product.

Comment: I know what the weak gradient is and I know what the distributional gradient is, but I'm not able to figure out what the distributional divergence could be. Could you give a definition?

Comment: Essentially you have to consider $\nabla \cdot u$, as in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where you wrote $\nabla p (\phi):=\sum_{i=1}^d ...$ it's not the gradient, but should be the divergence.

Comment: You mean my $\nabla p$ is not the distributional gradient but the distributional divergence of $p$?

Comment: Yes, the distributional gradient is a vector. And $\nabla p (\phi)$ extends the notion of divergence distributions, as in $\mathbb{R}^n$, or for functions of several variables.

Comment: How do you then define the distributional gradient? If $f\in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ is weakly differentiable and $$\langle f\rangle:=\left.\langle\;\cdot\;,f\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}\right|_{\mathcal D(\Omega)}\in\mathcal D'(\Omega)$$ denotes the distribution associated to $f$, then $$\nabla\langle f\rangle=\left.\langle\;\cdot\;,\nabla f\rangle_{L^2(\Omega,\:\mathbb R^d)}\right|_{\mathcal D}\;,$$ where $\nabla f$ is the weak gradient of $f$. That's why I thought my $\nabla p$ would be the distributional gradient.

Comment: @0xbadf00d the weak or distributional gradient follows directly from the definition of weak or distributional derivative. For example, $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ if $\partial_j u \in L^2(\Omega)$ $\forall j=1,...,d$, i.e. if weak gradient $\nabla u :=(\partial_1 u , ..., \partial_d u) \in L^2(\Omega) \times \cdot \cdot \cdot \times L^2(\Omega)$

Comment: Yes, the weak gradient is not my problem. But how do you define the distributional gradient?

Comment: It's the same thing, instead of arriving in the Lebesgue product space, you use the distributional derivative $D^\alpha : u \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega) \longrightarrow D^\alpha  u \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ and arrivals in the product space $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega) \times \cdot \cdot \cdot \times \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d as I said, the weak derivative is just the restriction of distributional derivative. For example, with $j=\alpha$ you have $\nabla u := (\partial_1 u , ..., \partial_d u) \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)^d$, and in this case you have the gradient distributional. Anothertypical example, can be the divergence of the distributional gradient, that is still a distribution, so the Laplacian in the sense of distributions.

Comment: So, with $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i}$ defined as in the question, $$\nabla p:=\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_d}\right)^T:\mathcal D(\Omega)\to\mathbb R^d\;,$$ right?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Are you really sure that $$(\nabla\cdot p)(\phi):=\sum_{i=1}^d\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i}(\phi_i)\;\;\;\text{for }\phi\in\mathcal D(\Omega)^d$$ (for $p\in\mathcal D'(\Omega)$ is the correct definition of the distributional divergence? I would say that it should be better defined for $p\in\mathcal D'(\Omega)^d$ by $$(\nabla\cdot p)(\phi):=\sum_{i=1}^d\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial x_i}(\phi)\;\;\;\text{for }\phi\in\mathcal D(\Omega)\;.$$ [And I would say that $\nabla p$ in the question is neither the distributional gradient nor the distributional divergence.]

Comment: I take the example of the Laplacian. Let $u \in L^{1}_{loc}(\Omega)$, then the Laplacian in the sense of distributions is \begin{align*}
\displaystyle T_{\Delta u}(\varphi) := \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 T_u}{\partial^2 x_j}(\varphi)=\sum_{j=1}^n T_u \left( \frac{\partial^2 \varphi }{\partial^2 x_j} \right) = \sum_{j=1}^n \int_\Omega u \frac{\partial^2 \varphi }{\partial^2 x_j} dx = \int_\Omega u \Delta \varphi dx , \forall \varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)
\end{align*} this is the same as taking the divergence of the distributional gradient.

Comment: In other words $T_{\Delta u}(\varphi) := (\mathrm{div} \cdot \nabla T_u) (\varphi)$, where $T_u$ is a distribution, $\nabla T_u := (\partial_1 T_u, ...., \partial_n T_u)$ is distributional gradient, $\mathrm{div}:=(\partial_1 , ..., \partial_n)$ and $\cdot$ is standard scalar product.

Comment: In other words, you agree to my new definition of $\nabla\cdot p$ in my last comment, right? I'm just asking cause you've said before that the $\nabla p$ from the question would be the definition of the distributional divergence.

Comment: Yes, and basically you should take a vector of distributions. In the case of Laplacian take the distributional gradient.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathcal D (\Omega, \Bbb R^d)$ is the space of *vector-valued* test functions, there is a topology on it, very similar to the Schwartz topology on $\mathcal D (\Omega)$, that makes it a locally-convex topological linear space. It makes sense, then, to consider its topological dual, $\mathcal D ' (\Omega, \Bbb R^d)$, the elements of which are called *vector-valued distributions*. Formally, $\mathcal D ' (\Omega, \Bbb R^d) = \underbrace {\mathcal D ' (\Omega) \oplus \dots \oplus \mathcal D ' (\Omega)} _{d \text{ times}}$, in the topological sense.

To begin with, let $p : \Omega \to \Bbb R^d$ be a smooth vector-valued map. Then $\text{div } p$ is a smooth function, which we may view as a distribution, and its action on a vector-valued test function $\varphi$ is

$$\langle \text{div } p, \varphi \rangle = \left< \sum _i \partial_i p_i, \varphi \right> = \sum _i \langle \partial_i p_i, \varphi \rangle = \sum _i \int (\partial_i p_i) \varphi = \\
\sum _i \int \partial_i (p_i \varphi) - \sum _i \int p_i \partial_i \varphi = \sum _i 0 - \int \sum _i p_i \partial_i \varphi = - \int \langle p, \nabla \varphi \rangle = - \langle p, \nabla \varphi \rangle ,$$

where the last $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ means evaluation of a distribution on a test function, and the $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ immediately preceding it is the scalar product in $\Bbb R^d$.

This justifies defining the divergence of a vector-valued distribution $p$ as $\langle \text{div } p, \varphi \rangle = - \langle p, \nabla \varphi \rangle$.